# Angular js 1 : stateProvider ... how to configure state and its child state once parent is resolved and then child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

```
I am working on angular js state providers...I am using parent states and its child states.
```

For example ..
Parent state is 'home'(url:/home) and its child state is 'home.profile'(url:/home/profile)

Each states are having the resolve: methods

Inside resolve methods i am calling the webservices.

My problem is when i am hitting the home.profile both resolves are called parellely

But i want to call the profile state once after home state is resolved

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post the route configuration code?